# sketchup wont install through wine

Tags: wine

I tried installing sketchup on my pc. I set wine to emulate windows 7

When I try to install sketchup it says   Component Visual C++ "14" Runtime Libraries (x64) has failed to install with the following error message:
"Service does not exist. "

The following components were not installed:
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 and x64)

The following components failed to install:
- Visual C++ "14" Runtime Libraries (x64)

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3

Comment: I updated wine to the latest version and now it give me another error                    
          Component Visual C++ "14" Runtime Libraries (x64) has failed to install with the following error message:
"Service does not exist. "

The following components were not installed:
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 (x86 and x64)

The following components failed to install:
- Visual C++ "14" Runtime Libraries (x64)

Comment: Did you try to use wine tricks to install those Libraries? `winecfg`

Comment: no the sketchup installer was trying to install the libraries